# How to use std::mem_fn to call a method on all objects inside a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, ostream

Given a vector such as:

```
vector<Something*> a;
```

I want to call function `whoAmI()` on every `Something` object. I want to append the return value (`string`) to an `ostream` for all objects inside the vector.

Here's my code:

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outstream_), std::mem_fn(&Something::whoAmI)));
```

EDIT: My bad, forgot the reference.

Answer (score 3):

After adding a missing `&` in the argument to `mem_fn`, [**your code works**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b95d1092b246d23).

However, why use `transform` here in the first place? The proper solution to your problem is

```
for (auto s : a)
    outstream_ << s->WhoAmI();
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, correct. That is a left-over from ten minutes ago, where I still thought that the vector contains the actual objects (and not the pointers to them).